# htaccess can't redirect if directory has uppercase characters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to perform a redirect for one of my directory's that has a mixture of uppercase and lower case characters. However the uppercase characters are causing issues.

For example attempting the following redirect works correctly:

```
RewriteRule ^mydirectory\/(.*)$$ "http\:\/\/www\.google\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

However the directory i'm trying to redirect is has a mixture of uppercase and lowercase i.e

```
RewriteRule ^MyDirectory\/(.*)$$ "http\:\/\/www\.google\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

However, this does not redirect and is simply ignore.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `NC` (ignore case) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^mydirectory/(.*)$ http://www.google.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Try this in a new browser

Comment: Ok it works thanks. I had another htaccess rule that was overriding this.

Comment: Glad to know, please accept the answer if it worked.